# What does a 2D Halbach array look like?

Tags: magnetics

A 1D Halbach array looks like the below:

[image]

What would it look like in 2D, in order to make a square array?

Comment: there are a few articles on the internet

Comment: https://www.blogs.uni-mainz.de/fb08-physics-halbach-magnets/

Comment: @jsotola think you could put one those articles in an answer and then I can select it? Unfortunately, I found no explanation of how to arrange the magnets for a 2D grid when I did a search.

Comment: Does the arrangement shown in the Wikipedia article on Halbach array, image reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Halbach_planar_array.svg, satisfy your curiosity?

Comment: @V.V.T yes, that's exactly it! I had been doing searches for "2D" and not finding anything. I see that the keyword I should have been using is "planar" instead. Could you make that an answer and I'll give it the nod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the [Wikipedia page on Halback arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halbach_array) presents an image of "a planar Halbach array", which is unique in the sense that this arrangement never reveals itself in web search results with keywords 'Halbach array' (with various modifiers like planar, 2D, square etc.), 'magnetic levitation', 'wiggler magnets' and the like. So I cannot recommend nor dismiss this find, if you are going to research it with practical purpose in mind.

[image: Halbach_planar_array.svg]

(C) CC BY-SA 4.0, Wikipedia, Uploaded: 5 April 2017

When analyzing field distribution in this arrangement, be careful with intuitive methods: the magnetic field and magnetic dipole are axial vectors, and the axial vector transformation properties can appear counter-intuitive. Even if your spatial imagination is an extraodinary asset, verify your consideration with simulators like COMSOL.

If your only goal is to have an arrangement extended in the transverse direction, you can use rectangular magnets elongated in this direction, like those shown in the schematic diagram of a free-electron laser:

[image: HalbachArrayFEL2]

(C) CC BY-SA 3.0, Wikipedia, 11 November 2010

Comment: Good observations about the lack of literature on the image. I did find it odd that it's buried quite far down on the page, and only in a "magnetic levitation" caption.